# Why I can't access child field when use inheritance in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

```
using System;
class MyClass
{  
    public static void Main()
    {
        Student a = new Student();
        Person y = new Gamer();

        Console.WriteLine(a.X);
        Console.WriteLine(y.X); <=== Error here
    }
}

abstract class Person
{
    public abstract void Display();
}

class Student : Person
{
    public int X { get; set; } = 1;
    public override void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Student");
    }
}

class Gamer : Person
{
    public int X { get; set; } = 1;
    public override void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Gamer");
    }
}
```

Hi,
I've tried to inherit Student, Gamer class from Person. In the code above, I don't know why y object cannot access to X - property of Gamer class.

Please, help me to explain. Thanks

Comment: Because the variable `y` is of type `Person`. `Gamer y = new Gamer()` if you want `y` to be of type `Games`, which will let you access Gamer's members

Comment: or cast `y` to be a `Gamer`

Comment: Or you could use `var` instead of `Gamer` as such `var y = new Gamer()` Or with the new syntax it could be `Gamer y = new();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just edit this line:

```
// Person y = new Gamer(); ==> Person does not have a field named X
Gamer y = new Gamer();
```